# Loopback 4 exception in authentication

Tags: javascript, typescript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've followed along the loopback 4 tutorial for adding a jwt authentication to an application. It works but I have a question.

At the end of the guide there is :

[image: Lb4 guide]

On the picture we add security to all the routes through the SECURITY_SPEC.

So my first question is : I want to add two expections to this, login and register routes. For obvious reasons, I can't access the app otherwise. 
Second question : I have an unauthorized 401 page when add the the security like that and not a page full of locks. I get that I can't access since I've put security on it but how is it accessed on the tutorial then?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

You can use authentication decorator on the method level in the documentation you can see this being done in the controller for example:

```
@get('/users/me', {
**security: OPERATION_SECURITY_SPEC**,
```

then inside this.api

```
  this.api({
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  info: {title: pkg.name, version: pkg.version},
  paths: {},
  components: **{securitySchemes: SECURITY_SCHEME_SPEC}**,
  servers: [{url: '/'}],
});
```

Those changes should result in something like here:
[image]

Have a look here for more details:
[Loopback Auth Tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-Tutorial.html)

For the second questions once you apply those changes it will get sorted.